# Duvidas com timessquare CalendarPickerView

Tags: android

Como desativar o dia da semana exemplo:Tenho calendário, passei o dia da semana por parâmetro no caso Segunda,Quinta e Domingo para marcar serviço. Como faço para desativar Terça,Quarta e Sexta usando timessquare CalendarPickerView?

Pesquisei em alguns em alguns lugares que o método init() consegue desabilitar os dia mas não consegui fazer com que pegue somente os dia da semana.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="webservice.tablayout.teste"
android:id="@+id/layout">
```

```
public class AgendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Servico servico;

private SimpleDateFormat sdFormat;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_agendar);

    Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
    nextYear.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);

    CalendarPickerView calendar = (CalendarPickerView)      findViewById(R.id.calendarPV);
    Date today = new Date();

    calendar.init(today, nextYear.getTime()).withSelectedDate(today);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom dia Xará!

Nunca usei o CalendarPickerView mas sempre o DateTimePicker do próprio Android. Infelizmente o DateTimePicker não é um componente bastante flexível como você precisa, por exemplo, pintando de vermelho os dias da semana que o usuário não poderia escolher.

Porém, para oferecer uma alternativa, você poderia usar o próprio DatePickerDialog tratando o evento de retorno da atribuição da data:

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

    }
};
```

Neste listener, você pode verificar se o dia da semana é aceito. Caso não for, gentilmente informe o usuário por meio de um Toast ou Snackbar, instruindo o que ele deveria fazer porém não impedindo ele de clicar sobre uma data, reabrindo o calendário por exemplo.

Espero ter ajudado,

Comment: No caso não preciso fazer dessas flexibilidades de pintar, no caso precisaria do mais importante o resultado que em questão seria desativar os dias da semana, vou realizar teste com DateTimePicker e volto para dar uma resposta, valeu pela ajuda ;)

Comment: @Matheus legal! Tomara que consiga resolver o problema. Caso tenha mais dúvidas sobre, comente! Abraço

Comment: Dei uma procurada não consegui achar o método que quando clico no calendário chama um método, você pode me dizer qual é ?